# What does 'equating the like-power of $q$' mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, homotopy-theory

I am reading a book "[Homotopy Analysis Method in Nonlinear Differential Equations](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/820/bok%253A978-3-642-25132-0.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fbook%2F10.1007%2F978-3-642-25132-0&token2=exp=1463982039~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F820%2Fbok%25253A978-3-642-25132-0.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fbook%252F10.1007%252F978-3-642-25132-0*~hmac=5f7f7f2fd38f3875ceee710ba0dd3ceefb7b7196a7dd2bc92ee40d048ccef63d)" by Shijun Liao chapter 13 Applications in Finance: American Put Options.

It is stated there that

> Substituting the series (13.27) and (13.28)into (13.15),(13.16)and (13.18),then equating the like-power of $q$, we have the so-called $n$th-order deformation equation ($n \geq 1$)
>
> \begin{equation}
>  \label{ 13.32 }
>  -\frac{\partial V_n(S,\tau)}{\partial \tau}+S^2\frac{\partial^2 V_n(S,\tau)}{\partial S^2}+\gamma S \frac{\partial V_n(S,\tau)}{\partial S}-\gamma V_n(S,\tau)=0
>  \end{equation}
>
> subject to the initial/boundary conditions
>
> \begin{equation}
>  \label{ 13.33 }
>  V_n(S,0)=0,
>  \end{equation}
>    \begin{equation}
>  \label{ 13.34 }
>  \lim_{S\rightarrow \infty} V_n(S,\tau)=0,
>  \end{equation}

where equation (13.27), (13.28), (13.15), (13.16), and (13.18) are

\begin{equation}
\label{ 13.27 }
\phi(S,\tau;q)=V_0(S,\tau)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n(S,\tau)q^n,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{ 13.28 }
\Lambda(\tau;q)=B_0(\tau)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n(\tau)q^n,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{ 13.15 }
-\frac{\partial \phi(S,\tau;q)}{\partial \tau}+S^2\frac{\partial^2 \phi(S,\tau;q)}{\partial S^2}+\gamma S \frac{\partial \phi(S,\tau;q)}{\partial S}-\gamma \phi(S,\tau;q)=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{ 13.16 }
\phi(S,0;q)=0,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{ 13.18 }
\lim_{S\rightarrow \infty} \phi(S,\tau;q)=0,
\end{equation}

Note: series (13.27) and (13.28) are homotopy-Maclaurin series where

\begin{equation}
\label{13.29}
\begin{split}
& V_n(S,\tau)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\partial^n \phi(S,\tau;q)}{\partial q^n}\bigg|_{q=0}=\mathcal{D}_n[\phi(S,\tau;q)],\\
& B_n(\tau)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\partial^n \Lambda(\tau;q)}{\partial q^n}\bigg|_{q=0}=\mathcal{D}_n[\Lambda(\tau;q)],\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
are the $n$th-order homotopy-derivatives of $\phi (S, \tau ;q)$ and $\Lambda(q)$, respectively, and $D_n$ is the $n$th-order homotopy-derivative operator.

I don't understand what "equating the like-power of $q$" mean and thus I have no idea how to obtain the first three equations. I considered asking this question in ell.stackexchange.com but I think it's better to ask it in this site.

Can anyone tell me what does "equating the like-power of $q$" mean by explaining (step by step) how to get equation the first three equations?

OR, could anyone please tell me what is "like-power" or give any reference about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have power series $\sum_{n\geq0}a_nq^n$ and $\sum_{n\geq0}b_nq^n$, and you know that they are equal, then you know that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\geq0$. That is «equating the like powers of $q$» in the two series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, does it mean that "Equating the like power of $q$" is "equating the coefficient of the corresponding power of $q$"? And, if you don't mind, could you please help me elaborate step by step (or at least give me hint) of how to get the first equation of my question?

Comment: No, I won t do that. That would be answering a completely different question than the one you posed! I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Pardon me, I am afraid I didn't catch it. Could you point out the difference? And, about my previous question in my comment before, can I say "Equating the like power of q" is the same as "equating the coefficient of the corresponding power of q"?

Comment: Yes, equating the like powers of $q$ means exactly equating tthe corresponding coefficients. That is what my answer says! :-)

Comment: This question is about the meaning of a particular phrase in a certain context. Explaining how to get the first equation you wrote is an answer to the question "How do I get the first equation blah", which is, as you see, rather different. The latter you would not have asked on ell.stackexchange.com but th first you might: that shows that the two questions are quite different!

Comment: Okay, thank you for both the answer and explanation! I am going to pose another question.